# why is drawableLeft appearing outside the EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

Why is the icon appearing before the `EditText`/divider?

Here's my code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragment_sign_in"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context="com.*.*.*.SignInFragment">

   <!-- This is the EditText -->
  <com.rey.material.widget.EditText 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/email"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:hint="test"
    app:et_dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Make the padding from 0 to some value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
 android:drawablePadding="5dp" // Add your own values
```

**The padding between the drawables and the text.**

> Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended
>   with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp
>   (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred
>   font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).

You can try with

```
 android:drawableLeft="2dp" 
 android:paddingLeft="3dp"
```

> The drawable to be drawn to the left of the text.

Comment: Sir he has used `com.rey.material.widget.EditText` may be this library will this properties supported to that ?

Comment: @jaydroider Oh .I thought its user custom class sir

Comment: I think this properties will not recognized by library which he has used may be it have it's own `properties for padding`.

Comment: @jaydroider Sir ,Indeed indeed

Comment: The library extends EditText, so it contains the attributes. I'll try this when I get home

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I used the following code for the above EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha"
    />
```

Comment: he has used `com.rey.material.widget.EditText` may be this library will not support this attributes.

Comment: How does this solve my problem if it has the same code as the one I have?